# tweepy bad authentication data

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to access twitter api via tweepy. And I get `tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 215, 'message': 'Bad Authentication data.'}]` error.

My API access is decribed in `twitter_client.py`:

```
import os
import sys
from tweepy import API
from tweepy import OAuthHandler

def get_twitter_auth():
    """Setup twitter authentication
    Return: tweepy.OAuthHandler object
    """

    try:
        consumer_key = os.environ['TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY']
        consumer_secret = os.environ['TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET']
        access_token = os.environ['TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN']
        access_secret = os.environ['TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET']
    except KeyError:
        sys.stderr.write("TWITTER_* environment variable not set\n")
        sys.exit(1)

    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

    return auth

def get_twitter_client():
    """Setup twitter api client
    Return: tweepy.API object
    """
    auth = get_twitter_auth()
    client = API(auth)

    return client
```

Then I try to get my last 4 tweets:

```
from tweepy import Cursor
from twitter_client import get_twitter_client

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = get_twitter_client()

    for status in Cursor(client.home_timeline()).items(4):
        print(status.text)
```

And get that error. How do I fix it?

I am using python 3.6 and I've installed tweepy via pip whithout specifying a version, so it should be the last version of tweepy.

Upd: I found out that the problem is in environ variables. Somehow twitter api can't get it. However, when I just `print(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)`, everything is on it's place

Answer (score 0):

```
import tweepy
```

Importing this way improves code readability especially when using it.
eg tweepy.API()

```
client.home_timeline()
```

The brackets after home_timeline shouldn't be there.

should be

```
for status in Cursor(client.home_timeline).items(4):
    print(status.text)
```

.

```
import tweepy 

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(<consumer_key>, <consumer_secret>)
auth.set_access_token(<access_token>, <access_secret>)

client = tweepy.API(auth)

for status in tweepy.Cursor(client.user_timeline).items(200):
    process_status(status.text)
```

Comment: Thanks, but my goal is to store tokens in evnironment, not as a plaintext like this  
`auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(<consumer_key>, <consumer_secret>)
auth.set_access_token(<access_token>, <access_secret>)`

Answer (score 0):

You may solve this problem by importing load dotenv, which will get .env variables.

```
import os
import sys
from tweepy import API
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from dotenv import load_dotenv
def get_twitter_auth():
    """Setup twitter authentication
    Return: tweepy.OAuthHandler object
    """

    try:
        consumer_key = os.getenv('CONSUMER_KEY')
        consumer_secret = os.getenv('CONSUMER_SECRET')
        access_token = os.getenv('ACCESS_TOKEN')
        access_secret = os.getenv('TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET')
    except KeyError:
        sys.stderr.write("TWITTER_* environment variable not set\n")
        sys.exit(1)

    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

    return auth

def get_twitter_client():
    """Setup twitter api client
    Return: tweepy.API object
    """
    auth = get_twitter_auth()
    client = API(auth)

    return client

from tweepy import Cursor


if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = get_twitter_client()

    for status in Cursor(client.home_timeline()).items(4):
        print(status.text)
```